# Menu With Shadow Effect

Tags: jquery, html, css

Please see the following image. I want to display some nav items in the following style.

[image: styled nav items]

I can display the texture box [rectangle box]. I could not display the shadow effect on the top and bottom. The shadow effect depends upon the text size. Is this possible to do? Any ideas on how to proceed?

Comment: This is what you need: **http://www.matthamm.com/box-shadow-curl.html**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this using radial gradients on pseudo-elements - [**DEMO**](http://dabblet.com/gist/3401346)

CSS:

```
ul {
    margin: 5em auto;
    padding: 0;
    background: silver;
    text-align: center;
}
li {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    margin: 1em;
    padding: .1em 2em;
    background: #414141;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}
li:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: -1.3em;
    right: 0;
    bottom: -1.3em;
    left: 0;    
    background: radial-gradient(at 50% 0, rgba(0,0,0,.35), rgba(255,255,255,0)) 0 85%,
        radial-gradient(at 50% 100%, rgba(0,0,0,.3), rgba(255,255,255,0)) 0 15%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% .5em;
    content:'';
}
```

**EDIT**: A second version that is also supported by IE9 - [**DEMO**](http://dabblet.com/gist/3401808)

This one uses two pseudo-elements on the list item and requires that the list item has a child.

CSS:

```
ul {
    margin: 5em auto;
    padding: 0;
    background: silver;
    text-align: center;
}
li {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    margin: 1em;
    text-align: center;
}
li:before, li:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: -.4em;
    bottom: -.4em;
    content:'';
}
li:before {
    z-index: 2;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 0 2em -.5em #000;
}
li:after {
    z-index: 3;
    right: -2em;
    left: -2em;
    background: silver;
}
a {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: .1em 1.5em;
    background: #414141;
    color: white;
    line-height: 1.6;
    text-decoration: none;
    z-index: 4;
}
```

Comment: perfect @Ana i was also thinking the same as yours anwer :-)

Comment: Hi ana. I need one more help. The shadow should display Ie9. Is it possible??

Comment: I have an idea about how that could be achieved, but it requires one more pseudo-element and I'll have to test it first, so it will take a few minutes.

Comment: No No. Don't say like this. Your answer is very very useful 4 me. Client asked this feature. Thanks once again.

Comment: I did it! :D I'm pretty grateful to you as well. For making me think a bit ;) I like CSS challenges. Check my updated answer.